# Pentagonal tiling

Tags: reference-request, polygons, tiling

I am currently working on a research project in my last year of high school. For this paper we are discussing Eschers tesselations, both in the euclidian and the non-euclidian plane. At the moment I am focussing on an article about pentagonal tilings in the euclidian plane, since this project is mainly focussed on math I am trying to give a decent proof of why these pentagons can tile the plane. I have been trying to read Karl Reinhardt's paper but since its in german and its written in 1916, I am a little lost.

I have discussed this with both my partners and my teachers but we can't seem to find any decent proof. Could you give me a hand? Maybe you know some papers which discuss the subject?

Your help is very welcome!

Thank you,

Roy

Comment: Could you name Escher's actual work you're thinking about? Regular pentagons *don't* tile the standard Euclidean plane, and none of his hyperbolic things really make me think of pentagons.

Comment: First of all, yes, my mistake, it's Karl Reinhardt.

Comment: Our research mainly focusses on the circle limit drawings. However, our teacher told us we should also include tesselations of the euclidian plane and give examples of that, he stated that we should discuss the three regular tilings, the semiregular tilings and tilings made of convex pentagons. Thank you for your comments and please excuse my English.

Comment: Have you read Schattschneider's Mathematics Magazine article from 1978?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-4_pentagonal_tiling

Comment: "I am trying to give a decent proof of why these pentagons can tile the plane."  The Wikipedia article gives an explanation of how the five kinds of pentagons in Reinhardt's paper form tile-transitive tilings (i.e. by assembling them in units of two or four to give tiles with "wallpaper" symmetry).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "The symmetries of things" by J. Conway, C. Goodman-Strauss & H. Burgiel, for learning the very basics of symmetries of tilings. Also in "Tilings and Patterns" by Grumbaum & Shephard you should find whatever you need, though the first option is IMO much more friendly.

I also suggest you to look at this [note](http://www.ams.org/notices/201006/rtx100600706p.pdf), [pentaplexity](http://world.mathigon.org/resources/Polygons_and_Polyhedra/Pentaplexity.pdf) by Penrose and Martin Gardner's [column](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/radin/gardner3.jpg).